# How to get data from django rest framework request field

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models: Printer and Check

### models.py

```
class Printer(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(...)
    api_key     = models.CharField(...)
    check_type  = models.CharField(...)                                    
    point_id    = models.IntegerField()

class Check(models.Model):
    printer_id      = models.ForeignKey(Printer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type            = models.CharField(...)
    order           = JSONField(...)
    status          = models.CharField(...)
    pdf_file        = models.FileField(...)
```

I am building API using Django REST Framework. And I am getting POST request that should look this way:

### request "/create_checks/"

```
{
  "id": 123456,
  "price": 780,
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "pizza",
      "quantity": 2,
      "unit_price": 250
    },
    {
      "name": "rolls",
      "quantity": 1,
      "unit_price": 280
    }
  ],
  "address": "some address",
  "client": {
    "name": "John",
    "phone": his phone
  },
  "point_id": 1
}
```

Every point(place where food is cooking) has two printers. I need to create two **Check** objects so one "check" prints for kitchen and one for client. For that I am going to use "point_id" from request and create two Check

### views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_checks(request):
    queryset = Check.objects.all()
    orderid = #order_id from request
    point = #point_id from request
    jsonorder = #request body converted to json
    printers = Printer.objects.filter(point_id=point)
    kitchencheck = Check(printer_id=Printer.objects.get(name=printers[0].name), 
                        type="kitchen", order=jsonorder,status="new")
    clientcheck = Check(printer_id=Printer.objects.get(name=printers[1].name), 
                        type="client", order=jsonorder,status="new")
    kitchencheck.save()
    clientcheck.save()
    return Response({"Success": "Checks created successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

1. How do I get order_id and point_id from request? 
2. How can I conver request body to JSON file? 
3. Is there easier way to do it? I've spent whole day trying to understand DRF and "result" looks too bulky and unrealistic

Comment: If anyone as dumb, as me: `orderid = request.data['id]   point = request.data['point_id'], jsonorder = request.data`. And remember that JSONField is postgres thing and will not work with default django sqlite DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what serializers are for. (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) At the View-level, pass your request through a serializer, which will give you a `validated_data` payload. This in turn you can use to create model instances. Just repeat the last step twice if you need to create two model from one set of data.

```py
class CheckSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.CharField()
    point_id = serializers.CharField()
    # etc ..

@api_view(['POST'])
def create_checks(request):
    queryset = Check.objects.all()

    serializer = CheckSerializer(data=request.data,
                                context={'request': request})
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

    printers = Printer.objects.filter(point_id=serializer.validated_data['point_id'])

    kitchencheck = Check(
        printer_id=Printer.objects.get(name=printers[0].name), 
        type="kitchen",
        order=jsonorder,
        status="new"
        )

    clientcheck = Check(
        printer_id=Printer.objects.get(name=printers[1].name), 
        type="client",
        order=jsonorder,
        status="new"
        )

    kitchencheck.save()
    clientcheck.save()
    return Response({"Success": "Checks created successfully"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```